# How to prevent rendering of whole Map while displaying marker info(tooltip of marker) with google-maps-react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

I have following class with `google-maps-react` library. Note : visibility of marker info(tooltip about location) is controlled by `visible` property of `InfoWindow` which I set through `setState()` on click event of associated marker. **Problem is** : This causes re-rendering of whole map with all the markers and I have hundrends of markers so flickering is visible while displaying location info.
How can I solve this flickering issue?
Any way to only render `<InfoWindow>`  child component without rendering whole `Map` (parent) component on maker click event?

```
import { Map, Marker, InfoWindow } from "google-maps-react";
...
class MyMap extends Component {
...
...
render() {
return (
<Map 
   ....
   ..../>
  <Marker .../>
  <Marker .../>
   ...
   ...
  <Marker .../>
  <InfoWindow visible = {this.state.visible} ..../>
  <Info>
  </InfoWindow>
</Map>
)}
}
```

Comment: Did you use a wrapper as stated in the documentation?

Comment: Which documentation, react, googl-maps-react? Could you provide link?

Comment: [google-maps-react](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react)

Comment: Went through documentation, but didn't come across anything which solves this thing.